# Como colocar um contador regressivo com números aleatórios?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Estou tentando criar um contador de produtos regressivo com javascript.

- Começando com um numero que eu determinar. Ex.: 357
- Passado alguns segundos. Ex.: 2s
- Esse valor diminui aleatoriamente. Ex.: 159, 78, 25
- Estou querendo colocar ele dentro de uma class.
- Fazer esse função três vezes na tela.
- Quando chegar no zero bloqueasse um botão especifico.

Seria possível fazer isso com javascript?

Ex.:

```
$(".date").html( moment().format('DD/MM/YYYY') );

var inicio_5 = 337;
var inicio_3 = 494;
var inicio_1 = 150; //327
var inicio_5_var = 13;
var inicio_3_var = 22;
var inicio_1_var = 16;
var hora = moment().format('h');

inicio_5 = inicio_5 - (hora*inicio_5_var);
inicio_3 = inicio_3 - (hora*inicio_3_var);
inicio_1 = inicio_1 - (hora*inicio_1_var);

$(".pacotes_disponiveis_5").html(inicio_5);
$(".pacotes_disponiveis_3").html(inicio_3);
$(".pacotes_disponiveis_1").html(inicio_1);

(function(){
var counter = inicio_5;

setInterval(function() {
valor = Math.floor((Math.random() * 3) + 1);
counter = counter-valor;
if (counter >= 0) {
  $(".pacotes_disponiveis_5").html(counter).hide().show('slow');
}

if (counter <= 14) {
    $(".pacotes_disponiveis_5").html(14);
    clearInterval(counter);
}

}, 5000);
})();

(function(){
var counter = inicio_3;

setInterval(function() {
valor = Math.floor((Math.random() * 3) + 1);
counter = counter-valor;
if (counter >= 0) {
  $(".pacotes_disponiveis_3").html(counter).hide().show('slow');
}

if (counter <= 9) {
    $(".pacotes_disponiveis_3").html(9);
    clearInterval(counter);
}

}, 4000);
})();

(function(){
var counter = inicio_1;

setInterval(function() {
valor = Math.floor((Math.random() * 5) + 1);
counter = counter-valor;
if (counter >= 0) {
  $(".pacotes_disponiveis_1").html(counter).hide().show('slow');
}

if (counter <= 0) {
    clearInterval(0);
    $(".pacotes_disponiveis_1").html('0');
    $(".pacote_1 .utm span").html('ESGOTADO');
    $(".pacote_1 .utm").attr('href','#').attr('disabled',"disabled").addClass('btn-red');
    $(".pacote_1 .pacotes-disponiveis").attr('href','#').attr('disabled',"disabled").addClass('btn-red');
    clearInterval(counter);
}

}, 3000);
})();
```

Comment: Tirando a parte da class, acho que totalmente possível, basta você explicar um pouco melhor não está dando para entender

Comment: Tentei organizar melhor, vê se está melhor para entender @FelipeDuarte.

Comment: O que você esteve tentando?

Comment: Tentei com jquery mas ainda estou aprendendo, não sei bem se é isso, vou colocar na pergunta, para mostrar melhor.

Comment: Coloca o código Javascript que você já tem (onde quer executar esse contador), e o código dos botões que você quer bloquear...

Comment: Ok, já coloquei, mas gostaria da opinião de vocês se é melhor em javascript puro ou jquery.